# Initializing Array of structs

Tags: array, struct

I defined myself a struct:

```
typedef struct {
  unsigned char current;
  unsigned char start;
  unsigned char target;
  unsigned long startTime;
  unsigned int duration;
} led;
```

I was able to initialize an instance of that like this:

```
led h_red = {0,0,255,0,300};
```

However, when I try to have them in an array:

```
led leds[LEDS];
leds[0] = {0,0,0,0,0};
leds[1] = {0,0,0,0,0};
leds[2] = {0,0,255,0,300};
```

I get this error

```
signal:28:1: error: 'leds' does not name a type
 leds[0] = {0,0,0,0,0};
 ^~~~
signal:29:1: error: 'leds' does not name a type
 leds[1] = {0,0,0,0,0};
 ^~~~
signal:30:1: error: 'leds' does not name a type
 leds[2] = {0,0,255,0,300};
 ^~~~
```

And I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here. You can see the full change [here on GitHub](https://github.com/iGEL/c-signal/commit/f27b9fa8ee9325455efe2c99100cbf0b04785257#diff-2cf64226463199d393dbbb66a4d404277bbe98a068de58e26005121d8368ea24R28-R30)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> ```cpp
> led h_red = {0,0,255,0,300};
> ```

Here, you are defining a variable, and at the same time giving it an
initial value. This is called an *initialization*.

> ```cpp
> led leds[LEDS];
> ```

Here you are defining an array. Since it is in global scope, and not
explicitly initialized, it is implicitly initialized to all bytes zero.

> ```cpp
> leds[0] = {0,0,0,0,0};
> ```

Here, you are trying to give a value to an element of the array that has
already been defined previously. This is thus *not* an initialization,
but an *assignment*. Unlike initializations, assignments cannot exist
outside a function. If you want to assign initial values, you can do it
in `setup()`.

Alternatively, you can initialize the array while you define it:

```cpp
led leds[LEDS] = {
    {0, 0,   0, 0,   0},
    {0, 0,   0, 0,   0},
    {0, 0, 255, 0, 300}
};
```

Comment: This is the key part to notice: **Unlike initializations, assignments cannot exist outside a function. If you want to assign initial values, you can do it in `setup()`.** OP's call to `leds[0] = {0,0,0,0,0};` is perfectly valid within another function, such as `setup()`, but is NOT allowed outside of all function scopes, where only initialization can take place. The OP was accidentally trying to do this assignment in the global scope, where new assignments and regular logic code are not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

I've upvoted [@Edgar Bonet's answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/80237/7727), because it is correct.

I want to add some more examples and explanations though.

### Key summary:

In C and C++, you can NOT have code *logic* outside of functions. The global context outside of functions is intended for *declarations*, *definitions*, and some *initializations*/*constructors* only. All code *logic* must be *inside of a function*. Code *logic* includes post-construction variable assignments, `if` statements, etc.

### Examples:

#### 1. NOT allowed:

**Therefore, you can NOT do the following, since it attempts to do non-initializing *assignments* outside of all function scopes.**

Notice also that in C++ (which Arduino is), you don't need to use `typedef` for structs either, so I've removed that from the `struct` definition. I'm also using the [stdint.h types](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdint/), which are considered safer and "best practice" for data types, as they specify the exact type size in bits. Use `uint8_t` in place of `unsigned char`, `uint32_t` instead of the Arduino Uno's `unsigned long`, and `uint16_t` instead of the Arduino Uno's `unsigned int`. Also, in C++ in particular, [`constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) or enums are preferred over `#define` to set variable constants.

```cpp
constexpr uint8_t NUM_LEDS = 3;

struct Led {
  uint8_t current;
  uint8_t start;
  uint8_t target;
  uint32_t startTime;
  uint16_t duration;
};

Led leds[NUM_LEDS];
// NOT OK: Variable (re)assignments are NOT allowed outside of functions in 
// C and C++.
leds[0] = {0, 0,   0, 0,   0};
leds[1] = {0, 0,   0, 0,   0};
leds[2] = {0, 0, 255, 0, 300};

void setup()
{
}

void loop()
{
}
```

#### 2. IS allowed:

**You CAN, however, have variable *initializations* outside of functions, so long as they occur at the same time as *construction*, so this is perfectly valid:**

```cpp
Led leds[NUM_LEDS];
// This form of aggregate initialization during construction is just fine in the 
// global scope outside of all functions. 
Led leds[NUM_LEDS] = {
    {0, 0,   0, 0,   0},
    {0, 0,   0, 0,   0},
    {0, 0, 255, 0, 300},
};

void setup()
{
}

void loop()
{
}
```

#### 3. Also IS allowed:

**Or, you can just move your reassignments into a function, such as `setup()`:**

```cpp
Led leds[NUM_LEDS];

void setup()
{
    // This variable (re)assignment is just fine since it's inside 
    // of a function.
    leds[0] = {0, 0,   0, 0,   0};
    leds[1] = {0, 0,   0, 0,   0};
    leds[2] = {0, 0, 255, 0, 300};
}

void loop()
{
}
```

#### 4. Full, runnable example on a PC:

**Here's a full, runnable example on a PC, with printing to verify the contents of the struct were changed:**

Run it online yourself [on OnlineGDB here](https://onlinegdb.com/MnEOQgCQT), or from my [eRCaGuy_hello_world](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world) repo here: [struct_array_initialization.cpp](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/cpp/struct_array_initialization.cpp):

```cpp
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Get the number of elements in a C-style array 
#define ARRAY_LEN(array) (sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]))

constexpr uint8_t NUM_LEDS = 3;

struct Led {
  uint8_t current;
  uint8_t start;
  uint8_t target;
  uint32_t startTime;
  uint16_t duration;
};

// To initialize once at construction. This form of aggregate initialization 
// can be used anywhere: both inside and outside functions. 
Led leds[NUM_LEDS] = {
    { 1,  2,  3,  4,  5},
    { 6,  7,  8,  9, 10},
    {11, 12, 13, 14, 15},
};

// Print the full contents of an array of `Led` structs
void printLeds(const Led ledArrayIn[], size_t ledArrayLen)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < ledArrayLen; i++)
    {
        printf("ledArrayIn[%lu]\n"
               "current   = %u\n"
               "start     = %u\n"
               "target    = %u\n"
               "startTime = %u\n" 
               "duration  = %u\n\n",
               i,
               ledArrayIn[i].current,
               ledArrayIn[i].start,
               ledArrayIn[i].target,
               ledArrayIn[i].startTime,
               ledArrayIn[i].duration);
    }
}

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World\n\n");

    printLeds(leds, ARRAY_LEN(leds));
    
    printf("==============\n\n");
    
    // Do this to set or change the structs at any time AFTER construction!
    // This variable (re)assignment is only allowed inside of a function, NOT 
    // in the global scope outside of all functions!
    leds[0] = {10, 20,  30,  40,  50};
    leds[1] = {60, 70,  80,  90, 100};
    leds[2] = { 0,  0, 255,   0, 300};
    
    printLeds(leds, ARRAY_LEN(leds));

    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```cpp
Hello World

ledArrayIn[0]
current   = 1
start     = 2
target    = 3
startTime = 4
duration  = 5

ledArrayIn[1]
current   = 6
start     = 7
target    = 8
startTime = 9
duration  = 10

ledArrayIn[2]
current   = 11
start     = 12
target    = 13
startTime = 14
duration  = 15

==============

ledArrayIn[0]
current   = 10
start     = 20
target    = 30
startTime = 40
duration  = 50

ledArrayIn[1]
current   = 60
start     = 70
target    = 80
startTime = 90
duration  = 100

ledArrayIn[2]
current   = 0
start     = 0
target    = 255
startTime = 0
duration  = 300
```

### Other references:

1. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization
2. [my answer] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61240589/how-to-initialize-a-struct-to-0-in-c/61240590#61240590

Comment: Regarding the first paragraph of your answer; What does "I've upvoted @Edgar Bonet's answer, because it is correct." have to do with the question?